# Update PDF Properties From Within SharePoint 2010

Tags: pdf, sharepoint-2010

We have PDF documents that have 4 PDF properties assigned for security. PDF Documents are added to SharePoint 2010 library and we copy the values of the 4 PDF properties into the SharePoint library document properties (metadata) using ITextSharp and Document Added Event Receiver. All works fine. However...if user changes the SharePoint library document properties this does not affect the embeded PDF Properties. So when the PDF is downloaded "Send To…Download A Copy" and saved locally (e.g. harddrive) and the PDF Properties are viewed the original PDF properties and values are shown, not those assigned and modified in SharePoint.

Example PDF property "ExportControlled2" = "NO", copied into SharePoint library document property "Export Control" when PDF is added to library. User updates "Export Control" = "YES" in SharePoint. User saves copy of file to local harddive, document properties show "ExportControlled2" = "NO".

Is there any way to update PDF Properties (that stay with PDF document when downloaded from SharePoint) from within SharePoint? Lots of examples to update PDF properties of file outside of Sharepoint but not when file is held within SharePoint content database.